# Imported perimeter values changing in HEC-RAS during further addition of data

Tags: hec-ras

I'm new to HEC-RAS and am encountering a very odd problem. I am using the RAS Mapper and import a terrain and then a perimeter feature. I then calculate the grid and save the geometry. Then, I open the geometric editor and add a boundary condition, save that, and then add unsteady flow data and save that too. Once I am done with this I try to run the model however I get an error: `"Property table generation parameter: 'Face Conveyance Tolerance Ratio' is less than 0.0001'"`. When I go back to the RAS Mapper and open the attribute table of my perimeter, suddenly all the values have been changed to 0, even though they were larger than 0 before.

Why might these values be changing and how can I avoid this?

I figured out what was wrong. I had to change my computer's regional settings and put '.' as the decimal separator. Hope this may help somebody else out!

Comment: Hi @LisaSch, very good that you figured out the reason of the issue. I suggest you to write your solution under the *Answer*, it will help other people to easely find the cause of their error own problme too.